# give unique id to append child in java script DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just create multiple div and append in java script but I also need to give unique id to all append child so later I can change color of any div.

my view

```
<div class="main" style=" background-color: white">
        <div class="first">
          <div class="box"></div>
          <div class="box1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="2nd">
          <div class="box2"></div>
          <div class="box3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="third">
          <div class="box4"></div>
          <div class="box5"></div>
        </div>  
      </div> 
<script>
for(var i = 0; i< 5; i++)
     $(".first").append("<div class='box'></div><div class='box1'></div>");
for(var i = 0; i< 5; i++)
     $(".2nd").append("<div class='box2'></div><div class='box3'></div>"); 
for(var i = 0; i< 5; i++)
     $(".third").append("<div class='box4'></div><div class='box5'></div>"); 
</script>
```

Or is there any better method to achieve that?

Comment: in which way u will going to change color?

Comment: You can use something like `$('.first div').eq(4)` to select the 5th div inside `.first`

Comment: yeah it works,thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML DOM command .querySelectorAll() to return a list of children that match a given attribute. For example if you give your parent div an ID: id="mainDiv", and all the children divs the same class: class="childDiv", you can then do the following:

```
var mainDiv = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
var childrenDivs = mainDiv.querySelectorAll(".childDiv");

// childrenDivs is now a list containing all of your sections which you can reference using an index
// Eg...
childrenDivs[0].append();
```

Comment: Bear in mind index 0 refers to the first element in the list.